# Spring Boot: Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location ... is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I just upgraded the Spring Boot Starter Parent dependency **2.7.5 --> 3.0.2**.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Note that the application.yml already has the following **Legacy Processing** mode setting, which should prevent the error below:

```
spring.config.use-legacy-processing: true
```

There are different profiles defined in application.yml as follows:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: dev
  profiles: dev
  rails:
    url: ...
    userIdentifier: ...
    service: FILESERVICE
    methodInBody: POST
    uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations
   
---
spring:
  profiles: stage
  rails:
    url: ...
    userIdentifier: ...
    service: FILESERVICE
    methodInBody: POST
    uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
  rails:
    url: ...
    userIdentifier: ...
    service: FILESERVICE
    methodInBody: POST
    uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations
```

Error on `mvn spring-boot:run`:

> **org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException: Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [application.yml]' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 41:13]**

Do I just need to replace all 3 occurrences of `profiles:` with `spring.config.activate.on-profile:` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to re-write it as follows per this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73791460/1005607

- `spring.profiles` has to be replaced with
  `spring.config.activate.on-profile`
- if `spring.profiles.active`
  exists (this is still allowed), it cannot coexist with any
  `spring.config.activate.on-profile`

  ```
  spring:
     profiles.active: dev
     rails:
       url: ..
       userIdentifier: ..
       service: FILESERVICE
       methodInBody: POST
       uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations

   ---
   spring:
     config:
        activate:
            on-profile: stage
     rails:
       url: ..
       userIdentifier: ..
       service: FILESERVICE
       methodInBody: POST
       uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations
     jackson:
       serialization:
         indent-output: true
   ---
   spring:
     config:
        activate:
            on-profile: prod
     rails:
       url: ..
       service: FILESERVICE
       methodInBody: POST
       uri: /api/external-interfaces/file-locations
  ```